# Symfony - Using visitor design pattern inside entity to call the right service method

Tags: symfony, visitor-pattern

Here is a quite specific question about good/bad practices on symfony.
My issue is that, depending on the class of an entity I have different logics for the same action. My question is : is it ok to implement Visitor Design Pattern and passing a Symfony service as a parameter of an entity method ?

Example :

```
/**
 * Some service
 */
class Visitor {
    public function visitA(EntityA $entity)
    {
        ... some logic ...
    }

    public function visitB(EntityB $entity)
    {
        ... some different logic ...
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EntityA
{
    public function accept(Visitor $visitor)
    {
        $visitor->visitA($this);
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EntityB
{
    public function accept(Visitor $visitor)
    {
        $visitor->visitB($this);
    }
}
```

My question is purely and simply to know if such a structure would be good practice in symfony ? Since it would seem more natural that entities should not know about services... 
And if not, what would be an acceptable workaround ?

Comment: Maybe I don't well understand the question, but in general you should never inject any service into a Doctrine Entity because they should contain only low-level and simple logic or it will give you many headaches in the future (_code difficult/impossible to test and mantain, prone to errors, impossible to maintain entity's data validity/integrity and much other_). I would also avoid the use of Doctrine Events to manage some type of related logic, because it could heavily penalize your application performance (_but this can vary a lot depending by many factors_). So Decouple things

Comment: think about generalization? As you say is strange the service usage in that location. If you create a father class, you can customize the accept function behavior for each child class. But don't know if is good for your useCase.

Comment: Hello @gp_sflover, actually I don't see how to decouple this. My point is to avoid using a trivial if ($entity instanceof EntityA) { $this->visitA($entity) } elseif... inside my service.
But maybe that would be the most simple solution ? Could you please clarify how you would handle this case ?
But maybe my case is too general and that the only right answer to this question is "Don't do this"

Comment: Hello @NicolaPez I don't think generalization is the answer to my question. Since it would still require some complex logic (or a call to a service) inside my doctrine entities

Comment: @simsComputing "_But maybe my case is too general and the only right answer to this question is 'Do not do this'_" is exactly the reason of my previous comment. Without a specific use case I would prefer to start following the principle "keep things simple if these works for you" (_move that complex logic into one or more services_), also to avoid thinking too much on premature optimizations. On that way you'll acquire more knowledge to then take full advantage of the framework's potentials.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is move the accept method from entities to external Service, like this:

```
 /**
 * Some service
 */
 class Visitor { 

 public function accept($entity){

     switch (true) {
        case $entity istanceof EntityA:
            //some logic;

        case $entity istanceof EntityB:
            //some other logic;

        default:
            new \Exception('invalid class');
    }
}
```